# Ansible: Extract json objects from file based on a list

Tags: ansible

I have a json file like so

```
{
  "service_accounts": {
    "sql-automation": "Automation Service account for Cloud SQL Instances",
    "gke-proxy": "GKE proxy account",
    "gke-node": "Default GKE nodes service account",
    "syncdata": "Data sync between environments",
  }
}
```

Then I have another json file with the default access the accounts need (this is a template file)

```
{
    "key_gen_auths": {
        "worker": [{
            "role": "roles/iam.serviceAccountKeyAdmin",
            "members": [
                "serviceAccount:dataprovisioning@{{ project_id }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            ]
        }],
        "gke-node": [{
            "role": "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser",
            "members": [
                "serviceAccount:deployment-automation@{{ project_id }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            ]
        }],
        "sql-automation": [{
            "role": "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser",
            "members": [
                "serviceAccount:deployment-automation@{{ project_id }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

Then in the playbook, i would like to say:
If the service account exists in the service_accounts file, extract that object from key_gen_auths if it exists there (if it doesnt exist in key_gen_auths ignore). Ive looked at several options, like selectattr, combine, difference, but im no further than when i started really, and wonder if im just better with a when statement if i can find the right syntax, any help would be appreciated.

```
- name: Play for reading json
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    project_id: 123
  tasks:
  - name: acct_list
    set_fact:
      acct_list: "{{ lookup('template', 'acct_list.json') }}"
  - name: key_auth_default
    set_fact:
      keyauth_default: "{{ lookup('template', 'key_auths.json') }}"

  - name:
    set_fact:
      access_file: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ keyauth_default.key_gen_auths }}"
    when: item in acct_list.service_accounts

  - debug:
      var: access_file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the files without *lookup*

```yaml
  vars_files:
    - acct_list.json
    - key_auths.json
  vars:
    project_id: 123
```

give

```yaml
  service_accounts:
    gke-node: Default GKE nodes service account
    gke-proxy: GKE proxy account
    sql-automation: Automation Service account for Cloud SQL Instances
    syncdata: Data sync between environments

  key_gen_auths:
    gke-node:
    - members:
      - serviceAccount:deployment-automation@123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
    sql-automation:
    - members:
      - serviceAccount:deployment-automation@123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
    worker:
    - members:
      - serviceAccount:dataprovisioning@123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      role: roles/iam.serviceAccountKeyAdmin
```

---

Q: ***"If the service account exists in `service_accounts` extract that object from `key_gen_auths`."***

A: Get the lists of the keys from the dictionaries. Then the intersect of these lists gives the existing service accounts

```yaml
  service_accounts_list: "{{ service_accounts.keys()|list }}"
  key_gen_auths_list: "{{ key_gen_auths.keys()|list }}"
  service_account_exists: "{{ service_accounts_list|intersect(key_gen_auths_list) }}"
```

give

```yaml
  service_accounts_list: [sql-automation, gke-proxy, gke-node, syncdata]
  key_gen_auths_list: [worker, gke-node, sql-automation]
  service_account_exists: [sql-automation, gke-node]
```

Use the list of existing accounts to extract the objects and create a dictionary

```yaml
  access_file: "{{ dict(service_account_exists|
                        zip(service_account_exists|map('extract', key_gen_auths))) }}"
```

give

```yaml
  access_file:
    gke-node:
    - members:
      - serviceAccount:deployment-automation@123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
    sql-automation:
    - members:
      - serviceAccount:deployment-automation@123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

---

Example of the complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - acct_list.json
    - key_auths.json

  vars:

    project_id: 123
    service_accounts_list: "{{ service_accounts.keys()|list }}"
    key_gen_auths_list: "{{ key_gen_auths.keys()|list }}"
    service_account_exists: "{{ service_accounts_list|intersect(key_gen_auths_list) }}"
    access_file: "{{ dict(service_account_exists|
                          zip(service_account_exists|map('extract', key_gen_auths))) }}"
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: service_accounts
    - debug:
        var: key_gen_auths

#  If the service account exists in service_accounts
#  extract those objects from key_gen_auths

    - debug:
        var: service_accounts_list|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: key_gen_auths_list|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: service_account_exists|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: access_file
```

Comment: Intersect is a good one, thanks for this. I managed to get a working play but this one is a lot simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think this shows the data you want, in `debug`, and you can use that with `set_fact` as you see fit:

```
- name: Play for reading json
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
  - acct_list.json
  - key_auths.json
  vars:
    project_id: 123
  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ key_gen_auths[item] | default('Not Found') }}"
    loop: "{{ service_accounts.keys() }}"
    ignore_errors: yes
```